# Read/Write at the same time

Tags: c++

What I am doing is opening my file using fstream at the start of the main and closing it at the end. In between I am writing "Hello World" and after that reading what I wrote but the result is always weired charecters and not the "Hello World". I did do a cast to char but that didnt help. Any way I can do this?

Comment: Did you check if the read operation succeeded? How are you doing the read?

Answer (score 2):

You need to interpose an [fseek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fseek/) call when you switch from reading to writing, or viceversa.  (Of course, you also need to `fopen` for `"r+"` or the like, so that both reading and writing are allowed, but I imagine you *are* already aware of that -- the need for seeking in order to switch between reading and writing is a lesser known fact).

As [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/) puts it,

> For the modes where both read and
>   writing (or appending) are allowed
>   (those which include a "+" sign), the
>   stream should be flushed (fflush) or
>   repositioned (fseek, fsetpos, rewind)
>   between either a reading operation
>   followed by a writing operation or a
>   writing operation followed by a
>   reading operation.

Comment: fseek and fstream? I dont think so. The question is tagged C++ not C, so a C++ answer would be more appropriate.

Comment: @camh, in my answer, I quoted extensively from `cplusplus.com`: it's not my fault (nor is it the guys' at `cplusplus.com` of course;-) that C++ incorporates (a version of) C as a subset, and therefore this answer works just fine (while as @Mike's answer observes, doing it with `std::fstream` is _not_ quite as easy). If you think there's a better way to do it (with `std::fstream` and w/o `fopen`), why not just post it?

Comment: If I think there's something wrong with your answer, I will comment on it, as I have done. I do not need to post my own answer to participate. You cannot mix iostreams and stdio, so your answer is at best irrelevant (stdio is not relevant to a question about iostreams), and at worst, wrong. That C++ includes a subset of C does not mean it is a good idea to use that subset in a pure C++ program. Not being exception safe (no auto-closing of fopened files unless you write your own wrappers) is enough for me to discourage use of this C subset in pure C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be amused if this works, because I always had to open a file twice to do that: once for reading and once for writing.  Even then, I had to write the whole file out and close it (which flushed the OS buffers) before I could be sure I could read the whole file and not get an early EOF.

Nowadays, since I use Unix-style operating systems, I would just use the `pipe()` function.  Not sure if that works in Windows (because so much doesn't, like `select()` on files).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are seeking to the beginning of the file before reading, like so:

```
fileFStream.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);
```

If that doesn't work, post your code.